# Releasing unmanaged resources

Tags: scala

I'm developing a Scala library on top of the Java library LWJGL and I'm wondering what is the best approach to handling "deleting" unmanaged resources. For example, consider a (simplified) interface for managing shader objects:

```
trait ShaderType {
    val glenum : Int
}

case class VertexShader() extends ShaderType {
    val glenum = GL_VERTEX_SHADER
}

case class FragmentShader() extends ShaderType {
  val glenum = GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
}

case class Shader[ST <: ShaderType](src: String)(implicit st: ShaderType) {

  public val shaderID: Int = glCreateShader(st.glenum)
  glCompileShader(shaderID)

}

case class ShaderProgram(shaders: List[Shader[ShaderType]]) {
   val programID: Int = glCreateProgram()
   shaders.map(s => glAttachShader(programID, s.id))

   glLinkProgram(programID)

   def bind(): Unit = glUseProgram(programID)
   def unbind(): Unit = glUseProgram(0)

}
```

We could add a release method to ShaderProgram, for example:

```
def release(): Unit = {
  unbind()

  // Detach the shaders
  shaders.map(s => glDetachShader(programID, s.id))

  // Delete the program
  glDeleteProgram(programID);
}
```

We could, of course, also delete the shader objects but this assumes they are not being used in other shader programs. However, the problem I have with this approach is that it replies on the library user "remembering" to call release either at the right time, to avoid leaks, or at all! In a language like C++, using std::shared_ptr combined with destructors, for example,  I would be able to automatically manage the GL resources, but it is not clear to me how to do something similar using Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources in JVM are automatically released by GC, but it's [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java) to use GC handler as the time of calling GC is not predictable + related handlers may not be called in appropriate order ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781444/why-doesnt-the-jvm-destroy-a-resource-as-soon-as-its-reference-count-hits-0)). Traditional way to handle such things in Java is:

```
val resource = getResource()
try { 
  resource.doSomething 
} finally {
  resource.close()
}
```

In Java7 there is also [try with resources](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html) construction. There is no analog in scala but traditional scala way is to define DSL:

```
object managed {
  def apply[T, Q](c: AutoCloseable)(f: (T) => Q): Q = {
    try {
      f(c)
    } finally {
      c.close()
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
managed(getResource()){ resource =>
  resource.doSomething()
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634455/simple-scala-pattern-for-using-try-with-resources-automatic-resource-manageme) is also monadic solution (using external library). Such DSL-like constructions guarantees that resource will be automatically released before going outside of `resource` argument's scope.

Comment: What you are referring to is known as the loan pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762240/loan-pattern-in-scala

Comment: I don't see why you'd use a structural type when `AutoCloseable` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a library that can help you with this, I found [Scala ARM](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm) to be helpful.